# 4.7.9 Civimail Exclude Recipients

Tags: civimail

In prior versions, you used to be able to 'exclude' certain groups when creating bulk mailings. Where is this function now in 4.7.9 drupal civicrm? I'm not seeing a way to exclude groups now.

Answer (score 1):

The include/exclude was amalgamated into a single field, if you drop the recipients list down you should see something like this

[image]

Comment: Yes, however - how do you exclude a group that doesn't already appear on the 'exclude group' option?

Comment: All groups should appear if they are flagged as mailing groups. Ensure the group is marked as such. You can get to the group management from Contacts -> Manage Groups.

Comment: I find this implementation not very "user friendly" in installation with a lot of groups. For instance, one organization has more than 500+ groups for Mailing, and when they want to exclude groups the scrolldown takes forever to reach that section on the dropdown :(

Answer (score 0):

I found it. the key is to NOT start typing 'exclude' - Just click the dropdown arrow in the recipient box and then scroll and you'll see the list of groups to exclude.